# Hapood Map: 2 pass value setting (same map)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm working on a Hadoop map function. I want to iterate through the data  once (left -> right), then I want to iterate through the data (right -> left).

The first pass will set a value for every key (**but not emit it**), then the second pass will go through and if it has a *better* value (in my case a lower value) it will override the value. The pair will be emitted after the second pass.

What are my options for storing (without emitting) key value pairs and then re accessing them?

Thanks

Comment: can you provide any example of your input data and output format you want?

Comment: the key is Text (word) and the value is a double

Comment: What is better value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the values in the first pass and store them into a collection. Then in the second pass match the values stored in the collection as you keep on reading from right to left.

Comment: Collection as in an array or list?

Comment: Arrays won't be of much help, IMO. Map should be fine as you can match by the key directly.